# ¿Cómo hacer una expresión regular que rechace 2 consonantes seguidas?

Tags: regex, lenguaje-compilado, preg-match

Quiero formular una expresión regular que rechace todas las palabras de un lenguaje cuando se repitan 2 letras consecutivas.

Adjunto el ejercicio:

> El lenguaje de todas las cadenas no vacı́as que se pueden formar con las letras minúsculas `a`, `b` y `c` sin que haya dos consonantes seguidas. Por ejemplo, `baaaca` pertenecerá a este lenguaje, pero no `λ`, `abc` o `bb`.

Lo que llevo actualmente es:

```
a?(b|c)a*|(b|c)?a*
```

Comment: en que lenguaje de programacion? y que llevas intentado?

Comment: @MiguelZarate no estoy programando como tal, son ejercicios para la universidad jajaja! Actualmente estoy probando en [regex101](https://regex101.com)

Lo que llevo actualmente es:

a?(b|c)a*|(b|c)?a*

Comment: Pues si estas en esa pagina como puedes ver debes especificar un lenguaje para hacer pruebas, segundo de lo que llevas es nada simplemente estas escribiendo la expresion general para definir una Expresion Regular.

Answer (score 1):

Prueba con lo siguiente:

```
^(?:[bc]?a)*[bc]?$
```

Tienes una demo [aquí](https://regex101.com/r/geEsGj/1/).